# Error after adding second CSS to ckeditor_stylesheets in mytheme.info.yml

Tags: theming, wysiwyg

Per https://www.drupal.org/node/2717985  and  https://www.drupal.org/node/2589827

I added a second stylesheet to my functioning D8 site in `mytheme.info.yml`.  File exists in same css dir as style.css which is loaded into ckeditor and working fine.

```
ckeditor_stylesheets:
- css/style.css
- css/ckeditor_specific.css
```

The whole contents of new CSS is

```
.fcx-inner-accordion-content {
    display:block;  
}
```

Which is intended to show some normally hidden content for edits.

When the cache was flushed after the addition of the one line to the yml the site died with "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later."

Repeat flushes got same error and removing the one line and flushing brought site back up.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: _The website encountered an unexpected error._ is the generic error shown on the pages. You need to look at the logs to see what exactly happened. Generally, it means a PHP error, but without seeing the logs, we cannot tell you which error, and which module caused it.

Comment: @kiamlaluno  Thank you.  That was stupid of me.  Editor had indented with a tab in YML which killed config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was committing a very foolish sin when I did not think to check the logs when error occurred.  Thank you to @kiamlaluno for pointing this out.

Log of the error says quite clearly " YAML file cannot contain tabs as indentation" My editor was indenting with tabs automatically though the original stylesheet entry in YAML was indented with spaces.

Once removed all worked as intended.